# gksudo unable to set permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-mint

I am new to Linux, running Linux Mint 17 and am having trouble updating scripts and changing default lists using the terminal.

When using the command gksudo gedit to edit a script, after saving the changes, then closing the document the terminal throws:

```
(gedit:3633): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.ZXW0LX': No such file or directory  


(gedit:3633): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: No such file or directory  


(gedit:3633): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.EN8DMX': No such file or directory  


(gedit:3633): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: No such file or directory
```

This looks as though using gksudo writes the changes to file but is unable to save those changes, as the destination does not exist.  When looking at the changes they seem to have taken, but in subsequent sessions (after restarting), the changes seem to have reverted. 
This does not occur when using sudo gedit.

Comment: What exactly are you editing?

Comment: defaults.list and a 'cleaner script' for removing old packages, kernals and config files

Comment: So you edit `/etc/gnome/defaults.list`, then save the file, get these errors but if you then open the file again or `cat` it, you see the changes there. Then, after restarting the file has reverted? If so, it has nothing to do with these errors, there is some other process that is writing to the file.